# Grouping common elements of list of lists

Tags: python

I would like to group common elements from the list below:

```
l = [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['f','g'], ['d', 'e'], ['g', 'h'], ['c', 'x']]
```

I am excepting the result to be something like this:

```
{1: [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'x']], 2: [['f', 'g'], ['g', 'h']], 3: [['d', 'e']]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to track the end letter of each group as you add them to the resulting dictionary.  Because the groups are lists, both the end-tracking dictionary and the resulting dictionary will be referencing the same group instances.  So adding tuples to an existing group only needs to be done in the end-tracking dictionary.

```
l = [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['f','g'], ['d', 'e'], ['g', 'h'], ['c', 'x']]
ends   = dict()
result = dict()
for s,e in l:
    ends[e] = ends.pop(s,[])            # find/create group for tuple
    if not ends[e]:
        result[len(result)+1] = ends[e] # add new group to result
    ends[e].append((s,e))               # add tuple to group

print(result)
{1: [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'x')], 
 2: [('f', 'g'), ('g', 'h')], 
 3: [('d', 'e')]}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
new_dict = {}

for i, elem in enumerate(your_list):
    new_dict[i] = elem
```

Comment: This does not give the expected output.

Comment: What is the output you get? Why is it wrong?

Comment: Run it and compare to what the OP says they are expecting. Your code assigned a single index to every sublist.